# Not able to register dll using WIX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe, wix3.6, regasm

I have my contextmenu shell extension dll. I have used Heat.exe to create component for my dll and in install it works completely fine.
But I am not able to register my dll using wix installer. 
I have tried various options and nothing is working.

If I try to do manual registration using regasm.exe /codebase Myfile.dll it works.

Answer (score 1):

Regasm /regfile ( and therefore heat or InstallShield ) has a known behavior of not writing out user registration data.   In this situations you need to install your software on a VM and use a tool to  capture the registry before and after running regasm.  Then perform a difference report to see what was changed.  Take that and author it into your WXS.

Finally reset the VM and run your new install and verify that it worked.

Comment: In wix file all registry elements are matching but when I have taken snapshot it is adding at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\myval instead of HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\myval

Comment: Considering that Wow6432Node is just the 32bit registry view on a 64bit machine, that may be functionally equal.